# How do I calculate the overlap days in a dataframe in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to calculate the overlap days, row wise, in a data frame.
Data looks like this:

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|id|             begin|                end|              days|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|1|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-08 02:10:00| 7.090277777777778|
|1|2019-02-04 05:28:00|2019-03-05 19:29:00|29.584027777777777|
|1|2019-06-05 22:18:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|209.07083333333333|
|1|2019-05-17 16:25:00|2019-06-05 22:18:00| 19.24513888888889|
|1|2019-05-03 05:05:00|2019-05-17 16:25:00|14.472222222222221|
|1|2019-01-08 02:10:00|2019-02-04 05:28:00|           27.1375|
|1|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|             365.0|
|1|2019-04-22 18:45:00|2019-05-03 05:05:00|10.430555555555555|
|1|2019-03-05 19:29:00|2019-04-22 18:45:00| 47.96944444444444|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Here, the first entry spans across the year 2019 (365 days).
All other entries are overlapping with the first entry.
I want a function to calculate total days, which is 365 days in the dataset after removing the overlapping days.

I actually solved this problem in R but I'm unable to run for loops in PySpark.

I'm looking for an output like this.

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|     id|              begin|                end|              days|           overlap|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|1      |2019-01-01 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|             365.0|            0|
|1      |2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-08 02:10:00| 7.090277777777778| 7.090277777777778|
|1      |2019-01-08 02:10:00|2019-02-04 05:28:00|           27.1375|           27.1375|
|1      |2019-02-04 05:28:00|2019-03-05 19:29:00|29.584027777777777|29.584027777777777|
|1      |2019-03-05 19:29:00|2019-04-22 18:45:00| 47.96944444444444| 47.96944444444444|
|1      |2019-04-22 18:45:00|2019-05-03 05:05:00|10.430555555555555|10.430555555555555|
|1      |2019-05-03 05:05:00|2019-05-17 16:25:00|14.472222222222221|14.472222222222221|
|1      |2019-05-17 16:25:00|2019-06-05 22:18:00| 19.24513888888889| 19.24513888888889|
|1      |2019-06-05 22:18:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|209.07083333333333|209.07083333333333|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

The dates are never in order and there are scenarios where there is no overlap.

Scenario 2: No overlap

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|  id   |              begin|                end| days| over|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|2      |2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-12-25 00:00:00|358.0|    0|
|2      |2019-12-25 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|  7.0|    0|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
```

Scenario 3: Partial overlap

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|     id|              begin|                end| days| over|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|3      |2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-12-25 00:00:00|358.0|    0|
|3      |2019-12-20 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00| 12.0|    5|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
```

Scenario 4: More complicated
Here the first entry spans across first 358 days of 2019. Second entry is completely overlapping with the first and therefore all of the days are under over. The third entry doesn't overlap with second entry but overlaps 5 days with the first and therefore 5 days under column "over".

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|     id|              begin|                end| days| over|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|4      |2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-12-25 00:00:00|358.0|    0|
|4      |2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-11-25 00:00:00|328.0|328.0|
|4      |2019-12-20 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00| 12.0|    5|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
```

Basically, I want to know for how long a particular id was in force. I can't just take the max and min date and subtract them because there could be breaks between periods.

In R, I created another column called "overlap" and used the Overlap function in for loop to check all values against others.

R function that produces the desired output:

```
abc<-data.frame()
for (i in id) {
  xyz<- dataset %>% filter(id==i) %>% arrange(begin)

  for(j in 1:(nrow(xyz)-1)){
    k=j
    while(k<nrow(xyz)){
      xyz$overlap[j]<- xyz$overlap[j] + Overlap(c(xyz$begin[j], xyz$end[j]), c(xyz$begin[k+1], xyz$end[k+1])) 
      k=k+1
    }

  }
  abc<- bind_rows(abc,xyz)
}
```

I'm still learning pyspark and need help with this.

Response to the code snippet by @murtihash

Hi,
It looks closer to the answer but still not the result I'm looking for.
Output from your code

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
|     id|              begin|                end|             days|overlap|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
|7777777|2019-01-05 01:00:00|2019-04-04 00:00:00|88.95833333333333|      0|
|7777777|2019-04-04 00:00:00|2019-07-11 00:00:00|             98.0|      0|
|7777777|2019-07-11 00:00:00|2019-09-17 00:00:00|             68.0|      1|
|7777777|2019-09-17 00:00:00|2019-09-19 22:01:00|2.917361111111111|      0|
|7777777|2019-09-19 22:01:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|103.0826388888889|     -1|
|7777777|2019-09-19 22:01:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|103.0826388888889|     -1|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
```

Desired output should be:

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
|     id|              begin|                end|             days|overlap|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
|7777777|2019-01-05 01:00:00|2019-04-04 00:00:00|88.95833333333333|      0|
|7777777|2019-04-04 00:00:00|2019-07-11 00:00:00|             98.0|      0|
|7777777|2019-07-11 00:00:00|2019-09-17 00:00:00|             68.0|      0|
|7777777|2019-09-17 00:00:00|2019-09-19 22:01:00|2.917361111111111|      0|
|7777777|2019-09-19 22:01:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|103.0826388888889|103.082|
|7777777|2019-09-19 22:01:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|103.0826388888889|      0|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
```

Explanation: First four rows have no overlaps. The fifth and sixth row are exactly the same period(and not overlapping with the other rows), so for one of 5th or 6th row, the overlap should be 103.08 days

Update:
Not able to work on this particular scenario.
Output from code snippet @murtihash

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
|  imono|              begin|                end|              days|overlap|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
|9347774|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-08 02:10:00| 7.090277777777778|    0.0|
|9347774|2019-01-08 02:10:00|2019-02-04 05:28:00|           27.1375|    0.0|
|9347774|2019-02-04 05:28:00|2019-03-05 19:29:00|29.584027777777777|    0.0|
|9347774|2019-03-05 19:29:00|2019-04-22 18:45:00| 47.96944444444444|    0.0|
|9347774|2019-04-22 18:45:00|2019-05-03 05:05:00|10.430555555555555|    0.0|
|9347774|2019-05-03 05:05:00|2019-05-17 16:25:00|14.472222222222221|    0.0|
|9347774|2019-05-17 16:25:00|2019-06-05 22:18:00| 19.24513888888889|    0.0|
|9347774|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|             365.0|    7.0|
|9347774|2019-06-05 22:18:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|209.07083333333333|    0.0|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
```

Desired output:
This

```
 +-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
    |  imono|              begin|                end|              days|overlap|
    +-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
    |9347774|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-08 02:10:00| 7.090277777777778|    0.0|
    |9347774|2019-01-08 02:10:00|2019-02-04 05:28:00|           27.1375|    0.0|
    |9347774|2019-02-04 05:28:00|2019-03-05 19:29:00|29.584027777777777|    0.0|
    |9347774|2019-03-05 19:29:00|2019-04-22 18:45:00| 47.96944444444444|    0.0|
    |9347774|2019-04-22 18:45:00|2019-05-03 05:05:00|10.430555555555555|    0.0|
    |9347774|2019-05-03 05:05:00|2019-05-17 16:25:00|14.472222222222221|    0.0|
    |9347774|2019-05-17 16:25:00|2019-06-05 22:18:00| 19.24513888888889|    0.0|
    |9347774|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|             365.0|    365|
    |9347774|2019-06-05 22:18:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|209.07083333333333|    0.0|
    +-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
```

Or

```
 +-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
|  imono|              begin|                end|              days|overlap|

+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
|9347774|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-08 02:10:00| 7.090277777777778|    7.1|
|9347774|2019-01-08 02:10:00|2019-02-04 05:28:00|           27.1375|   27.1|
|9347774|2019-02-04 05:28:00|2019-03-05 19:29:00|29.584027777777777|   29.5|
|9347774|2019-03-05 19:29:00|2019-04-22 18:45:00| 47.96944444444444|   48.0|
|9347774|2019-04-22 18:45:00|2019-05-03 05:05:00|10.430555555555555|   10.4|
|9347774|2019-05-03 05:05:00|2019-05-17 16:25:00|14.472222222222221|   14.5|
|9347774|2019-05-17 16:25:00|2019-06-05 22:18:00| 19.24513888888889|   19.2|
|9347774|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|             365.0|    0.0|
|9347774|2019-06-05 22:18:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|209.07083333333333|  209.1|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
```

Explanation: second last entry spans the full year and all other entries are overlapping with that. So either the output is that the second last entry overlap= 365 or all the other entries have their days as overlap and second last entry have 0 days as overlap.

Update2:
Not able to work on this particular scenario.
Output from code snippet @murtihash (Update2)

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
|  imono|              begin|                end|              days|overlap|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
|9395123|2019-01-19 05:01:00|2019-02-06 00:00:00|17.790972222222223|   17.0|
|9395123|2019-02-06 00:00:00|2019-06-17 00:00:00|             131.0|    0.0|
|9395123|2019-01-19 05:01:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00| 346.7909722222222|    0.0|
|9395123|2019-06-17 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|             198.0|    0.0|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
```

Desired output:

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
|  id   |              begin|                end|              days|overlap|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
|8888888|2019-01-19 05:01:00|2019-02-06 00:00:00|17.790972222222223|   17.8|
|8888888|2019-02-06 00:00:00|2019-06-17 00:00:00|             131.0|    0.0|
|8888888|2019-01-19 05:01:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00| 346.7909722222222|    329|
|8888888|2019-06-17 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|             198.0|    0.0|
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------+
```

I really don't understand what your code snippet does and therefore I'm unable to tweak it for my purpose. Thanks for your help!

Comment: scenario 4 is not clear. 3rd is being compared with 1st row to get overlap 5, because date of first and second row is the same?

Comment: Hi @murtihash, Please check the scenario 4 again. I have added comments explaining it

Comment: can one row overlap with multiple rows in the same id? and what is your spark version?

Comment: Yes, in some cases, one row does overlap with multiple rows and I need to capture that as well. This is what I'm using on databricks: Attached to cluster: xxx, DBR 6.5 | Spark 2.4.5 | Scala 2.11

Comment: thats what i thought, check my solution and let me know if it satisfies all cases..

Comment: Yes, in fact, any one of the two row can have the overlap value (not necessarily the first one). Basically, I want to capture the total time id was in force. The dates for each id are set up very badly and tend to overlap each other. So, if I can figure out total overlap period, I can the add the days column and minus the overlap column to get the total days for the id.

Comment: okay i think i understand. assuming u have more than 2 identical rows, say u have 4, but u will only want 1 row to have overlap value right?

Comment: No, if there are 4 identical rows, then 3 of the rows should have overlap values. So, if I add up the days, I get 4* times the days in force and then I can minus the overlap days which will be 3* times the days (as 3 of the rows will have overlap values), which will give me the time that id was in force ( 4*days - 3* overlap (for 4 identical entries)

Comment: @HarkaranSaini, are you looking for the sum of overlap grouped by each id instead of the overlap on each Row(which can be multiple possibilities)?

Answer (score 1):

For **`Spark2.4+`**, you can use **`sequence`**(*generate date range*) , **`collect_list,`** and use a combination of array functions and higher order functions to get your desired overlaps.

```
df.show() #sample dataframe
#+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
#| id|              begin|                end| days|
#+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
#|  2|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-12-25 00:00:00|358.0|
#|  2|2019-12-25 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|  7.0|
#|  3|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-12-25 00:00:00|358.0|
#|  3|2019-12-20 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00| 12.0|
#|  4|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-12-25 00:00:00|358.0|
#|  4|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-11-25 00:00:00|328.0|
#|  4|2019-12-20 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00| 12.0|
#+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w1=Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy("begin")
df.withColumn("seq", F.expr("""sequence(to_timestamp(begin), to_timestamp(end),interval 1 day)"""))\
  .withColumn("seq1", F.expr("""flatten(filter(collect_list(seq) over\
                                (partition by id),x-> arrays_overlap(x,seq)==True and seq!=x))"""))\
  .withColumn("overlap", F.when(F.row_number().over(w1)==1, F.lit(0))\
              .otherwise(F.size(F.array_intersect("seq","seq1"))-1)).orderBy("id","end").drop("seq","seq1").show()

#+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-------+
#| id|              begin|                end| days|overlap|
#+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-------+
#|  2|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-12-25 00:00:00|358.0|      0|
#|  2|2019-12-25 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|  7.0|      0|
#|  3|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-12-25 00:00:00|358.0|      0|
#|  3|2019-12-20 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00| 12.0|      5|
#|  4|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-11-25 00:00:00|328.0|    328|
#|  4|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-12-25 00:00:00|358.0|      0|
#|  4|2019-12-20 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00| 12.0|      5|
#+---+-------------------+-------------------+-----+-------+
```

**`UPDATE`**:

This should cover all cases:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w1=Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy("begin")
w2=Window().partitionBy("id","begin","end").orderBy("begin")
w3=Window().partitionBy("id","begin","end")
w4=Window().partitionBy("id","begin","end","maxrownum").orderBy("begin")
df.withColumn("seq", F.expr("""sequence(to_timestamp(begin), to_timestamp(end),interval 1 day)"""))\
  .withColumn('maxrownum', F.max(F.row_number().over(w2)).over(w3))\
  .withColumn('rowNum', F.row_number().over(w4))\
  .withColumn("seq1", F.expr("""flatten(filter(collect_list(seq) over\
                                (partition by id order by begin),x-> arrays_overlap(x,seq)==True and seq!=x))"""))\
  .withColumn("overlap", F.when(F.row_number().over(w1)==1, F.lit(0))\
              .when(F.size(F.array_intersect("seq","seq1"))!=0,F.size(F.array_intersect("seq","seq1"))-1)
              .when((F.col("maxrownum")!=1)&(F.col("rowNum")<F.col("maxrownum")),F.col("days"))\
              .otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
         .orderBy("id","end").drop("seq","seq1","maxrownum","rowNum").show()

#+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
#|     id|              begin|                end|             days|          overlap|
#+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
#|7777777|2019-01-05 01:00:00|2019-04-04 00:00:00|88.95833333333333|              0.0|
#|7777777|2019-04-04 00:00:00|2019-07-11 00:00:00|             98.0|              0.0|
#|7777777|2019-07-11 00:00:00|2019-09-17 00:00:00|             68.0|              0.0|
#|7777777|2019-09-17 00:00:00|2019-09-19 22:01:00|2.917361111111111|              0.0|
#|7777777|2019-09-19 22:01:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|103.0826388888889|103.0826388888889|
#|7777777|2019-09-19 22:01:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|103.0826388888889|              0.0|
#+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**`UPDATE2:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w1=Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy("begin")
w2=Window().partitionBy("id","begin","end").orderBy("begin")
w3=Window().partitionBy("id","begin","end")
w4=Window().partitionBy("id","begin","end","maxrownum").orderBy("begin")
df.withColumn("seq", F.expr("""sequence(to_timestamp(begin), to_timestamp(end),interval 1 day)"""))\
  .withColumn('maxrownum', F.max(F.row_number().over(w2)).over(w3))\
  .withColumn('rowNum', F.row_number().over(w4))\
  .withColumn("seq1", F.expr("""flatten(filter(collect_list(seq) over\
                                (partition by id),x-> arrays_overlap(x,seq)==True and seq!=x))"""))\
  .withColumn("overlap", F.when(F.row_number().over(w1)==1, F.lit(0))\
              .when(F.size(F.array_intersect("seq","seq1"))!=0,F.size(F.array_intersect("seq","seq1"))-1)
              .when((F.col("maxrownum")!=1)&(F.col("rowNum")<F.col("maxrownum")),F.col("days"))\
              .when(F.col("maxrownum")==1,F.col("days"))\
              .otherwise(F.lit(0)))\
              .replace(1,0)\
         .orderBy("id","end").drop("seq","seq1","rowNum","maxrownum").show()

#+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
#|     id|              begin|                end|              days|           overlap|
#+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
#|9347774|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-08 02:10:00| 7.090277777777778|               7.0|
#|9347774|2019-01-08 02:10:00|2019-02-04 05:28:00|           27.1375|           27.1375|
#|9347774|2019-02-04 05:28:00|2019-03-05 19:29:00|29.584027777777777|29.584027777777777|
#|9347774|2019-03-05 19:29:00|2019-04-22 18:45:00| 47.96944444444444| 47.96944444444444|
#|9347774|2019-04-22 18:45:00|2019-05-03 05:05:00|10.430555555555555|10.430555555555555|
#|9347774|2019-05-03 05:05:00|2019-05-17 16:25:00|14.472222222222221|14.472222222222221|
#|9347774|2019-05-17 16:25:00|2019-06-05 22:18:00| 19.24513888888889| 19.24513888888889|
#|9347774|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|             365.0|               0.0|
#|9347774|2019-06-05 22:18:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|209.07083333333333|209.07083333333333|
#+-------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Hi murtihash, I have added my response above. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @HarkaranSaini please add that response to my snippet on ur question by editing ur question,that way community can see it on the question, instead of in my answer, and yes ill take a look ..

Comment: @HarkaranSaini check my update, it should cover all cases.. if there is anything left out, lmk i will check it out tomorrow

Comment: I think you are very close now. I updated the question with one scenario where it doesn't seem to work. Really appreciate your help brainstorming this one

Comment: Now it stopped working on another scenario (see my question)

Answer (score 0):

Check below solution, see if that works for you.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sc.parallelize([["1","2019-01-01 00:00:00","2019-01-08 02:10:00","7.090277777777778"],
["1","2019-02-04 05:28:00","2019-03-05 19:29:00","29.584027777777777"],
["1","2019-06-05 22:18:00","2020-01-01 00:00:00","209.07083333333333"],
["1","2019-05-17 16:25:00","2019-06-05 22:18:00","19.24513888888889"],
["1","2019-05-03 05:05:00","2019-05-17 16:25:00","14.472222222222221"],
["1","2019-01-08 02:10:00","2019-02-04 05:28:00","27.1375"],
["1","2019-01-01 00:00:00","2020-01-01 00:00:00","365.0"],
["1","2019-04-22 18:45:00","2019-05-03 05:05:00","10.430555555555555"],
["1","2019-03-05 19:29:00","2019-04-22 18:45:00","47.96944444444444"]]).toDF(("id","begin","end","days"))

df.withColumn("overlap", ((F.unix_timestamp(col("end")).cast("long") - F.unix_timestamp(col("begin")).cast("long"))/(24*3600))).show()

+---+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
| id|              begin|                end|              days|           overlap|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  1|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2019-01-08 02:10:00| 7.090277777777778| 7.090277777777778|
|  1|2019-02-04 05:28:00|2019-03-05 19:29:00|29.584027777777777|29.584027777777777|
|  1|2019-06-05 22:18:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|209.07083333333333|          209.1125|
|  1|2019-05-17 16:25:00|2019-06-05 22:18:00| 19.24513888888889| 19.24513888888889|
|  1|2019-05-03 05:05:00|2019-05-17 16:25:00|14.472222222222221|14.472222222222221|
|  1|2019-01-08 02:10:00|2019-02-04 05:28:00|           27.1375|           27.1375|
|  1|2019-01-01 00:00:00|2020-01-01 00:00:00|             365.0|             365.0|
|  1|2019-04-22 18:45:00|2019-05-03 05:05:00|10.430555555555555|10.430555555555555|
|  1|2019-03-05 19:29:00|2019-04-22 18:45:00| 47.96944444444444| 47.92777777777778|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: No, it's not a simple subtraction of columns.

Comment: Its per your expected output in question. If not, can you post expected output?

Comment: I have posted few different scenarios to clear up the confusion